# Localizing Facebook "scrapes"

Tags: facebook, localization, facebook-opengraph, facebook-canvas

We're running a canvas app that has fully localized og tags. Everything is working well except when users choose to manually copy the facebook app url (apps.facebook.com/mysite) into a post.

When that happens, we want the text in the posted message to be in the user's language.  Instead, it's always uses the English text from the `og:` meta tags.

If I could detect which culture the user came from, I could change those meta tags. However I don't see anything in the request header or parameters that are sent from the scraper to indicate where the user is coming from.

I did see that there's an `og:locale:alternate` tag I could use to specify other languages the page is available in, but unless I get a second request from Facebook with a locale value I don't see how that benefits me.

- How can I ensure the posted title/description is in the user's language?
- Must it be done using the Localization section in the Facebook App settings?

  - If so, is there a way to automate it? Our translation workflow is pretty well established and I don't want to send translators into the facebook app to finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need some parameter in the querystring to differentiate the urls.
e.g

http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/en/
or
http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/it/

this parameter will actually set the active language on your app.
And facebook **scraper** will cache the localized title/ description from the meta tags.